# Limiting Protected Accounts for Users

Tags: apex, trigger, account, limits

[image]

Edited Code - trying to limit 1000 Protected Accounts per user.  Protected Accounts are identified by a checkbox field.

Comment: You should read through [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices). Your code is not bulkified at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter by the checkbox as well:

```
Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    ownerIds.add(record.OwnerId);
}
Map<Id, AggregateResult> protectedAccountsPerUser = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
    [SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, OwnerId Id FROM Account
     WHERE OwnerId = :ownerIds AND
     Protected_Accounts__c = true
     GROUP BY OwnerId]);
for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.Protected_Accounts__c && protectedAccountsPerUser.containsKey(record.OwnerId) &&
       ((Decimal)protectedAccountsPerUser.get(record.OwnerId).get('sum') > 1000)) {
           record.Protected_Accounts__c.addError('You are limited to 1,000 protected accounts. Please deselect some other accounts first.');
       }
}
```

Comment: Interesting - So by aliasing the ownerId field as ID it will automatically put the OwnerId as the Key for the map when Instantiating the map from the query? Thats a neat little trick.

Comment: @Eric `Id` specifically. Capital I, lower-case d. It's one of my favorite tricks.

Comment: Nice and thank you for teaching me something again

Comment: @sfdcfox only question about that code is i noticed there is a ] at line 5, where would the open [ be? 

I keep getting a 'expecting right parenthesis expecting a right parentheses, found 'SELECT'.'  

If I add it before SELECT , i get 'The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type'

Comment: @B.Wayne I'm sorry, I forgot about that limitation. I've changed it to something the compiler should like. Try it out.

Comment: @sfdcfox i edited the code to reflect what you have shown.  I am still getting a "unexpected token: '{' at line 14 column 81"

I tried removing it but, and from looking online, it says depends if I am trying to define a static method or if I am doing something else?

Comment: @B.Wayne I'm sorry, I missed a `)` in the if statement. I've verified that this now works in my dev org.

Answer (score 1):

You are not filtering the query by whatever it is you use to identify protected accounts. So it will return all 1000 Accounts.

Change it to be like:

```
[SELECT COUNT()FROM Account WHERE Account.OwnerId=: accountOwner AND Protected_Accounts__c = True];
```

<strike>Besides the issues with best practices:</strike>

You are limiting the count to 2 in your code. so if they have more than 2 the error will be added.

`If(accounts > 2 )`

Change to:

`If(accounts > 1000 )`

Comment: I only have it as 2 because I was testing on sandbox.  When I pushed it to my production, I did have >1000.

Comment: Then update your question to reflect what is actually going on. You say it errors when user has 950 accounts well my answer is why

Comment: I've updated the code.  
The question still remains the same: I have the code limiting to 1000 Protected Accounts, however, when a user has 1000+ Accounts altogether I am getting the error.
I am pretty new to coding, so the concept of bulkifying is new to me, I am reading what was provide.

Comment: Does the code reflect what is actually deployed to the org. I do not understand why you would change it to 2 when posting the question so I have my doubts about what is deployed vs what you are posting

Comment: @B.Wayne - See updated answer

Comment: I deployed to Production with the code saying > 1000.  Since it was not working I had to change it in Sandbox again to do a few more test, and I just copied that code :).  But thank you for the new one, I will test it out now!

Comment: Ok, note on Test methods - How did it deploy to production and pass your test methods??? I bet you were not using system asserts to check to ensure that the expected result were achieved. Learn this lesson well. Read up on it. Don't repeat same mistake